# How to reset C array so all elements are 0

Tags: objective-c, c

If I have `int someArray[100]` that contains items in various elements, how can I reset them all back to 0?

Basic question, I know, but I usually use Objective-C arrays however for this purpose I'm just storing some numbers and want to deal with it "old school."

Comment: i was really looking for a more elegant solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set each element to the value you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    SomeArray[i] = 0;
```

For the specific case of integers and the value 0, you can also make use of the fact that their bitwise representation is known (all bits are 0), and so you can use `memset`:

```
memset(SomeArray, 0, sizeof(SomeArray));
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use [memset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/memset.3.html):

```
memset(someArray, 0, sizeof(someArray));
```

Comment: From a technical language-lawyer pedant's POV, this sets the bitwise representations to 0, not necessarily the values...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: language-lawyers generally don't write good code :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Incorrrect.  From n1516 section 6.2.6.2 paragraph 5, "For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type."

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Ah, I hadn't noticed the question was specifically asking about `int`s...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I agree. Good example could be actually wiping off virtual table pointer in high-level class stored in array, right? It's value will go foobar. But in this particular C-style case I think it is perfectly valid usage.

Comment: Thanks guys, but what in the world is n1516 section 6.2.6.2? Is that a joke or is that a real document somewhre?

Comment: @andrewx: It is ISO/IEC 9899:201x standard for C language. I.e. see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1516.pdf